# Prevent Symfony 2.8 from generating Repository Alongside with Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine

How to prevent the entity generator from generating the corresponding respository with an argument like --without-repository or in config.yml :

php app/console doctrine:generate:entity --entity=MyBundle:Article --format=annotation --fields="title:string(255) body:text" --no-interaction

In SF2.8, the repository is generated automatically.

Removing it manually is not envisageable for the requirement of my application.

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?  If you don't want a repository then don't call getRepository.

Comment: This command is called on my application not in console, and having repository breaks my application, I will either invent my command or unlink the generated file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the generators [Github Repository](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/blob/master/Command/GenerateDoctrineEntityCommand.php) you can see, that generating a repository is not optional. It is generated by using the [DoctrineEntityGenerator](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/blob/master/Generator/DoctrineEntityGenerator.php) which uses the [EntityRepositoryGenerator](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/EntityRepositoryGenerator.php) of doctrine.

It will be generated with this command. 
If you don't want that, why not write your own generator. Feel free to do so.